# If $1! \cdot 2! \cdot 3! \cdot\cdots\cdot 12! = m! \, n^2$, then what is $m$?

Tags: contest-math, factorial

Here's the problem:

> The super factorial number $1! \cdot 2! \cdot 3! \cdot\cdots\cdot 12!$ can be written as a factorial times a perfect square, that is, in the form $m! \cdot n^2$. What is the value of $m$?
>
> (A) $4 \qquad$ (B) $6\qquad$ (C) $8\qquad$ (D) $10\qquad$ (E) $12$

I don't understand a part of the solution, here is the solution:

> In the product $1! \cdot 2! \cdot 3!\cdot\cdots\cdot 12!$ change every second factorial as follows:
> $$\begin{align}
> 2! &= 1! \cdot 2 \\
> 4! &= 3! \cdot 4 \\
> 6! &= 5! \cdot 6 \\ 
> \cdots &= \cdots \\
> 12! &= 11! \cdot 12
> \end{align}$$
> This gives
> $$
> \begin{align}
> 1! \cdot 2! \cdot 3! \cdot \cdots \cdot 12! 
> &= (1)^2 \cdot 2 \cdot (3!)^2 \cdot 4 \cdot (5!)^2 \cdot 6 \cdot \cdots \cdot (11!)^2 \cdot 12 \\
> &= (1 \cdot 3! \cdot 5! \cdot \cdots \cdot 11!)^2 \cdot 2^6 \cdot 6! \\
> &= 6! × (1! \cdot 3! \cdot 5! \cdot \cdots \cdot 11! \cdot 2^3)^2
> \end{align}$$
>
> So $m = 6$, hence (B).

I'm confused on the third step "$(1 \cdot 3! \cdot 5! \cdot \cdots \cdot 11!)^2 \cdot 2^6 \cdot 6!$". I can see how they group the odd factorials together, but where did the $2^6$ and $6!$ come from?

I just need some clarification on this.

Comment: Do you recognize that $ 12 ! = 11 ! \times 12$? So after pulling out the 11!, we have  factor of 2 and a factor of 6. Do the same for the other even factorials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From this step:

$= (1!)^2 \cdot 2 \cdot (3!)^2 \cdot 4 \cdot (5!)^2 \cdot 6 \cdot \ldots \cdot (11!)^2 \cdot 12$

Group factorials and separate even numbers:

$= (1! \cdot 2! \cdot 3! \cdot \ldots \cdot 11!)^2 \cdot 2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6 \cdot \ldots \cdot 12$

Notice that each even number can be written in the form $2 \cdot n$, therefore if you have even numbers up to $k$ then $2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6 \cdot \ldots \cdot k = (2 \cdot 1) \cdot (2 \cdot 2) \cdot (2 \cdot 3) \ldots \cdot (2 \cdot \frac{k}{2}) = 2^{\frac{k}{2}} \cdot (1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot \ldots \cdot \frac{k}{2}) = 2^{\frac{k}{2}} \cdot (\frac{k}{2})!$ Since the twos multiple together and you're left with numbers starting from $1$ multiplying to $\frac{k}{2}$, which is the definition of factorial.

Therefore,

$= (1! \cdot 2! \cdot 3! \cdot \ldots \cdot 11!)^2 \cdot 2^{6} \cdot 6!$